# How to check for an update is done or not

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am updating a table s how could i check whether the update is successful or not . I am  storing the result in `$Result` and when i print it it gives me the following output.

```
CI_DB_mysqli_result Object
(
    [conn_id] => mysqli Object (
            [affected_rows] => 0
            [client_info] => mysqlnd 5.0.8-dev - 20102224 - $Revision: 310735 $
            [client_version] => 50008
            [connect_errno] => 0
            [connect_error] => 
            [errno] => 0
            [error] => 
            [field_count] => 0
            [host_info] => localhost via TCP/IP
            [info] => 
            [insert_id] => 0
            [server_info] => 5.5.16
            [server_version] => 50516
            [sqlstate] => 00000
            [protocol_version] => 10
            [thread_id] => 765
            [warning_count] => 0
    )
    [result_id] => 1
    [result_array] => Array ()
    [result_object] => Array ()
    [custom_result_object] => Array ()
    [current_row] => 0
    [num_rows] => 
    [row_data] => 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
you can check your affected rows in php like 
if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){ //affected rows}

or in codeigniter 

if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0)
{
    return TRUE;
}else{
    return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check for **error is empty**, like

```
if(!$this->db->_error_number()) {
  // update successful
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `$this->db->affected_rows()` to verify the actual update occured or not because `$this->db->_error_number()` would not raise any error if the update is not actually succeeded ie query executed but no change in the record. execute an update query with no changes in the values will return no error if using `$this->db->_error_number()` but will be noticed with `$this->db->affected_rows()`, that is what we want to know if the values are updated or not.

hope it makes sense.